# Listener for Apache / PHP before URL loaded?

Tags: php, apache

I would like to capture the HTTP-request for every incoming connection on port 80 / 443 (whether it is a valid URL on my server or not) and parse the info. One use-case that is relevant is if I wanted to reject every request from a particular USER_AGENT or IP_ADDRESS (or redirect them), rather than serving them a page. So, if a request came in from 22.22.22.22, I would like to parse their URI and redirect them to a different place than someone coming from 11.11.11.11. I want to do this regardless of what URL they are attempting to access (i.e. http://www.foo.bar/goodpage.php or http://www.foo.bar/nonexistentpage.php). Is there something similar to NSAPI or ISAPI either on the PHP engine level or the Apache level where I can inject this code?

I realize this may have performance implications, but I am willing to sacrifice some performance for function here.

Obviously, I will need this to service multiple clients concurrently as they connect.

Comment: Apache .htaccess/server config directives should be able to do that easily, e.g. mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

assuming this is done for 1 domain only  (and not for all sites on the server):
You can add this in your .htaccess file
(required is, mod_rewrite is enabled)

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^11\.11\.11\.11$
RewriteRule - /for_11-11-11-11.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^22\.22\.22\.22$
RewriteRule - /for_22-22-22-22.php [L]
```